# Adding to manytomany field, on added field from form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model, that needs a user(ForeignKey), and a category(M2M), and for the category field in form, I extended its functionality by adding custom field to it(data-list but with input too), but I am unable to save the form with the category and user.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

class Listings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    bid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering=['timestamp', 'title']
```

**forms.py**

```
from auctions.models import Listings
from django import forms

class ListTextWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self, data_list, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListTextWidget,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._name = name
        self._list = data_list
        self.attrs.update({
            'list':'list__%s' % self._name,
            'class':'form-control'
            })
    
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        text_html = super(ListTextWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs=attrs)
        data_list = '<datalist id="list__%s">' % self._name
        for item in self._list:
            data_list += '<option value="%s">' % item
        data_list += '</datalist>'

        return (text_html + data_list)


class ListingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'bid', 'image_url', 'category']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'bid': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'image_url': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _category_list = kwargs.pop('data_list', None)
        super(ListingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        self.fields['category'].widget = ListTextWidget(data_list=_category_list, name='category-list')
```

**views.py**

```
def create_listings(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #**what to do to save category and user**
            return redirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        category_list = Category.objects.all().values_list('name')
        form = ListingsForm(data_list=category_list)   
    return render(request, 'auctions/create_listings.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

How do I save all the data into a new Listing, during the form.save()?

I have tries using commit=False, but I get `ValueError:Field 'id' expected a number but got 'o'.`
Is there I way I can save all at once, or do I have to create a Listing, then manually add the remaining data after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, change the M2M field to foreign Key, then, in the form, there's not much to change, just remove category, and lastly in views add user after save(commit=False)
**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class Listings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    bid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    image_url = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="owner", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner')

    class Meta:
        ordering=['-timestamp', 'title']
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

**forms.py**

```
from auctions.models import Biddings, Comments, Listings
from django import forms

class ListTextWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self, data_list, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListTextWidget,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._name = name
        self._list = data_list
        self.attrs.update({
            'list':'list__%s' % self._name,
            'class':'form-control'
            })
    
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        text_html = super(ListTextWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs=attrs)
        data_list = '<datalist id="list__%s">' % self._name
        for item in self._list:
            data_list += '<option value="%s">' % item
        data_list += '</datalist>'

        return (text_html + data_list)


class ListingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'bid', 'image_url']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'bid': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'image_url': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _category_list = kwargs.pop('data_list', None)
        super(ListingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        self.fields['category'].widget = ListTextWidget(data_list=_category_list, name='category-list')
```

**views.py**
Here, I manually rendered the fields for clarification

```
def create_listings(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            description = form.cleaned_data["description"]
            bid = form.cleaned_data["bid"]
            image_url = form.cleaned_data["image_url"]
            category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(name = form.cleaned_data["category"])
            owner = request.user
            listing = Listings(
                title=title,
                description=description,
                bid=bid,
                image_url=image_url,
                owner=owner,  
                category=Category.objects.get(name = form.cleaned_data["category"])             
                )
            listing.save()
            messages.success(request, "Listing created succesfully")
            return redirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        category_list = Category.objects.all().values_list('name')
        form = ListingsForm(data_list=category_list)   
    return render(request, 'auctions/create_listings.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

I really hope this helps solve your answer :). Cheers

Comment: A little late, but I solved in a similar manner. All i really had to do was ```get_or_create``` the category